# for-loop add columns using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to add n columns to a table, like in this example of code where `n = 10`:

```
Sub toto()
    Dim db As Database, i As Integer
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    For i = 1 To i = 10 
         db.Execute " ALTER TABLE time_series " _
             & "ADD COLUMN F_" & i & " Number;"
         '  End If
    Next i
End sub
```

I tried to convert `i` in string with `CStr(i)` but to no avail. Any hint?

**EDIT**: No column is added.

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: No column was added because of the wrong for statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, I do not see any issues except for the fact, your For statement is a bit off and that you needed to set the db object. Try this code.

```
Sub toto()
    Dim db As Database, i As Integer
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For i = 1 To 10
        db.Execute " ALTER TABLE time_series " _
                    & "ADD COLUMN F_" & i & " Number;"
    Next i
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I setted the db object, I have forgotten it in the paste code. However, indeed, the problem came from the wrong for statement. Thank you.